# Spring RestController POST 400 Bad Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have a Spring RestController that any attempt to post to it returns 400 Bad Request despite seeing the correct data being sent in Chrome Developer Tools. The @Valid annotation is kicking it out because the ParameterDTO object is not being populated at all.

My Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/parameters", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE}, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public class ParameterResource {

    private final ParameterService parameterService;

    @Autowired
    public ParameterResource(ParameterService parameterService) {
        this.parameterService = parameterService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> getParameters(@RequestParam(value = "subGroupId", required = false) Integer subGroupId) {
        if (subGroupId != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(parameterService.getParameters(subGroupId));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(parameterService.getParameters());
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createParameter(@Valid ParameterDTO parameterData) {
        int id = parameterService.saveParameter(parameterData);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(id).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/levels")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getParameterLevels() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(ParameterLevels.getParameterLevelMap());
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/levels/{id}/values")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getLevelValues(@PathVariable("id") int levelId) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(parameterService.getParameterLevelValues(levelId));
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/types")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getParameterTypes() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(parameterService.getParameterTypes());
    }
}
```

I was using axios from JavaScript and though my problem might be there but I have the same issue using Postman. I am setting the Content-Type and Accept header. It seems like Spring is not deserializing the data at all.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you are missing `@RequestBody` before `ParameterDTO parameterData` declaration

Comment: That is not required the controller is declared as a @RestController, RequestBody was needed prior to that being added in Spring 4

Comment: yes, it is required. What `@RestController` gives you is `@ResponseBody` bounding, not `@RequestBody`

Comment: Ahhhh you are right, bone head mistake....... this is what happens when you switch between .NET and Spring. Thanks! If you make it an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `@RequestBody` annotation before `ParameterDTO parameterData` declaration, like below:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> createParameter(@RequestBody @Valid ParameterDTO parameterData) {
        int id = parameterService.saveParameter(parameterData);
        URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}")
                .buildAndExpand(id).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(uri).build();
    }
```